# What is the difference between returning a value inside a get, and assigning the property?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, properties, task

If I wanted to keep this handy for non async methods that return task.

```
public static Task CompletedTaskA { get { return Task.CompletedTask; } }

public static Task CompletedTaskB { get; } = Task.CompletedTask;
```

Should one be preferred over the other for any kind of context? Or are they the same? I also wonder the same with strings and basically anything i do with properties ie:

`get {return "some string"; }` vs `{ get; } = "some string";`

EDIT: I would like to clarify my usage of the above prop. I have several event handlers which have Task as a return type, offered to me by a library i'm using.  an example of one such event:

```
private Task Client_MessageReceived(Message message)
{
   Task.Run(async ()=> await HandleMessageReceived(message));

   // here is where i would use it
   return CompletedTask; // A OR B?
}

private async Task HandleMessageReceived(Message message)
{
   // Do stuff with message that might take long and block the handler
}
```

My intention is to save a completed task in a field (i'm choosing a readonly property in this case) and just keep using it to satisfy the task return. I am wondering if one of the above examples, keeps using the same completed task, and the other one keeps asking for another completed task every time?

Comment: Did you try to search fro existing solutions? There are many duplicates of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU6hxBSx6Avo0ZyZnAAzoA4gCcApqIAuASwB2AcwD6iFk26s5kvFADs6AEQALUQBtjAez0BuDiqI3W3NLwEjx0+Qph4NE6+gC8+kamFpbIbEA===) and look at the code for:

```
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
    }

    public string Greetig_1
    {
        get{return "hello";}
    }

    public string Greeting_2{get;} = "hello";
}
```

You can see that `Greeting_2` is backed by a member variable:

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly string <Greeting_2>k__BackingField = "hello";

    public string Greeting_1
    {
        get
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    public string Greeting_2
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Greeting_2>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public void M()
    {
    }
}
```

This follows through to the IL level. As `Greeting_2` is backed by a member variable that variable is initialized in the constructor.

In your example with `Task.CompletedTask` what you end up with is:

`public static Task CompletedTaskB { get; } = Task.CompletedTask;`

Caching the `Task`, whereas:

`public static Task CompletedTaskA { get { return Task.CompletedTask; } }`

Make a call to get the `CompletedTask` object in `Task` each time. In reality this will be inline by the JIT. The approach also has the advantage of not adding an additional (hidden) member variable to your class, which may be an issue if you've got lots of instances and are concerned about memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.
A properties get method is called every time you access it. By default when you create a property, it will have a hidden field behind it so:

```
public static Task CompletedTaskB { get; set; }
```

will actually generate this behind the scenes:

```
private static Task _completedTaskB;
public static Task CompletedTaskB 
{
 get {
  return _completedTaskB;
 } 
 set {
  _completedTaskB = value;
 } 
}
```

When you assign the property = Task.CompletedTask, you are setting its initial value which is equivalent to :

```
_completedTaskB = Task.CompletedTask;
```

When you then access the property, it will read from the private field.

I notice though that you are defining this as readonly (only a getter not a setter) so you will not be able to assign the variable. Instead you will have to use:

```
public static Task CompletedTaskA { get { return Task.CompletedTask; } }
```

This will return Task.CompletedTask all the time.

In general the difference between:

```
{ get; set; } = "some string";
```

and

```
get {return "some string"; }
```

is that the first is an initial assignment whereas the latter is a method that is called whenever you access the property.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to the property right at the definition, some "magic" happens behind the scenes.
The compiler creates a hidden backing field, and the value is assigned to that backing field in the constructor of the class.

In other words, you can think of the two classes below as working the same way.

```
class AssignedImplicit {
  public string Prop {get;} = "example";
}
class AssignedExplicit {
  private readonly string Prop_BackingField;
  public AssignedExplicit() {
      Prop_BackingField = "example";
  }
  public string Prop { get { return Prop_BackingField; } }
}
```

When you just define a get method without assigning, the backing field is not created, and no work is added to the constructor.

This is true for strings, or for any other type.
If you assign a value to the property, the work of constructing/fetching that value is put into the constructor of your class. If you create the value in the get method, then the work is put into the get method.